# detect initial android os version with which device was released

Tags: java, kotlin

It is possible that the user will update the operating system version. The current version of Android can be determined using 'build.version.release,' but I want to know which version of Android was released with which device. or the device's very first Android version

Is it possible to make this happen?

I'd like to determine the Android OS version that was present in the smartphone when it was purchased.

Comment: Not likely unless you find a mapping from device type to OS somewhere. And even then there's no guarantee that devices sold later will have a different version preinstalled. Why do you need this?